# iOS Obfuscation - How to get all symbols From iOS SDK Framework

Tags: ios, obfuscation

I'm currently working on a project to obfuscate some iOS code. It is a static library That contains a lot of intelligence, so I want to try to make my code a little more difficult to interpret.

So I am looking to rename all symbols of all objects. And to do That I need to know all the other symbols That I do not-have to rename, Those of SDK and all frameworks.

I have already started work to identify these symbols, but this method is very long. this is 
why I ask through this forum to get help and to Know if there are faster ways to retrieve a list of all the symbols of the iOS SDK.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "make my code a little more difficult to interpret" but that accomplished nothing, just makes it a little more work. So that probably will not save anything. But the obfuscation will make your job harder. Good tradeoff?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is a static library, so all symbols are visible. But there are some symbols that I did not want to be visible.

So I created a new project with the obfuscated code (I want to). may be it will be more difficult to manage both projects. One for debug and one for deliveries. but at least it guarantees a minimum of Intellectual Property.

Comment: A picture a minimum amount of [security](http://i.imgur.com/Al8YTuj.jpg?1), about what you get with obfuscation.

Comment: I can appreciate how you feel. The reality is that there is very little you can do to stop anyone from disassembling your code. IDA and Hopper and other disassemblers will unravel in a few seconds what will take you months to only half-bake.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to look at [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename) (on GitHub). It solves this problem by first analyzing the actual compiled binary (using code from [class-dump](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump)) and then pulling in all the references from that binary, analyzing those, and excluding everything found. That way it doesn't have to know all possible symbols to exclude; it just needs to know the ones that were used.

To get started, look at [CDClassDump.m](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename/blob/29ee631b17b2760898724107c63586a6dd94b3a9/Source/CDClassDump.m) at the [loadFile method](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename/blob/29ee631b17b2760898724107c63586a6dd94b3a9/Source/CDClassDump.m#L171). It parses the Mach-O binaries and identifies the load commands in them, then recursively follows those references to other binaries and parses them.

The symbols from those files end up being processed by [CDSymbolsGeneratorVisitor.m](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename/blob/29ee631b17b2760898724107c63586a6dd94b3a9/Source/CDSymbolsGeneratorVisitor.m). All the `visit*` methods are used to process particular types; see e.g. [visitProperty](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename/blob/29ee631b17b2760898724107c63586a6dd94b3a9/Source/CDSymbolsGeneratorVisitor.m#L738) for how it handles properties.

```
- (void)visitProperty:(CDOCProperty *)property {
    if (_ignored) {
        [self addForbiddenSymbol:property.name];
        [self addForbiddenSymbol:property.defaultGetter];
        [self addForbiddenSymbol:[@"_" stringByAppendingString:property.name]];
        [self addForbiddenSymbol:property.defaultSetter];
        [self visitType:property.type];
    } else {
        [_propertyNames addObject:property.name];
    }
}
```

Comment: it's good practice to disclose your connection to a given product/company (in this case [PreEmptive Solutions](https://www.preemptive.com/products/))